# Why the PHP code is not responding to AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

My API loaded from https://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html is not working. I don't know why... I checked the URL 1000 times but I don't know why is still broken. The code that I used is cURL, PHP, AJAX IN jQuery. I tried another APIs from their website and all worked but this. You know why? Thank you! Fore example it should respond and print all the information that the genonames provide, but instead it doesn't do anything, and I don't know where is the actually mistake,

```js
$('#BUTTON').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryInfo.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lat: $('#lat').val(),
            lng: $('#lng').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(result);

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                $('#countryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
                $('#countryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
                $('#city').html(result['data'][0]['city']);
                $('#name').html(result['data'][0]['name']);
            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // your error code
        }
    }); 

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta name="description" content="AJAX/PHP/CURL/JSON">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    
        <title>Project</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <select id="lat">
            <option value="40.78343">latitude</option>
        </select>

        <select id="lng">
            <option value="-73.96625">longitude</option>
        </select>

        <button id="BUTTON">START</button>

        <br><br>

        <div id="divResults">
            
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>countryCode: </td> 
                    <td id="countryCode"></td>
 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>countryName:  </td>
                    <td id="countryName"></td>    

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>city:</td> 
                    <td id="city"></td>    

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>name: </td>
                    <td id="name"></td>    

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

        <script  src="libs/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script  src="libs/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This `libs/php/getCountryInfo.php`, which is on your server, doesn't work?

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? Does the AJAX request take place? If so, what does PHP return in the response (you can check that in the Network tab of your Developer toolbar)?

Comment: Is not showing anything like I can give you an example of my code on github : https://github.com/DavidPetrut/Api-code.git

Answer (score 0):

#### As referred github.com/DavidPetrut/Api-code.git

### You don't need to use curl.

```
$('#BUTTON').click(function() {
    let url = `http://api.geonames.org/neighbourhoodJSON?formatted=true&lat=${$('#lat').val()}&lng=${$('#lng').val()}&username=demo&style=full`; //edit this URL for ur application.
    $.get(url,(data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        //rest of the code
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but do you know any possibility in how to do it using curl, because that is my task, to use these languages programs, thank you! I tried as well this code that I`m grateful you provided for me and it seems to not work as well, it worked when you tried it?

Comment: $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/neighbourhoodJSON?formatted=true&lat=$lat&lng=$lng&username=demo&style=full';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);